# Is HTTParty clearing a variable in responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I found a weird case using httparty, in one of the API I do receive expected JSON object expect one key which has an empty value. This key's name is PaymentToken. Wondering if this is some configuration to hide / clear value of variables with Token / Payment in the name?

I was trying to reproduce the same issue on Postman, with exactly the same request and receiving the same structure of object with the same keys values + PaymentToken value is there.

Postman:

```
{
    "ActionType": "RES",
    "IsActive": false,
    "BookingCode": null,
    "PaymentToken": "/ON9lFhfw2VYR9BiIep/peByEOtPSmtI7t+vxbcHFtsJctezBgS3mwKcVxSNCzZqKHXi4qPh8pMPGRMJOU6+1ZhSQ=",
    "Customer": null,
    "Mode": 0
}
```

HTTParty:

```
{
    "ActionType": "RES",
    "IsActive": false,
    "BookingCode": null,
    "PaymentToken": "",
    "Customer": null,
    "Mode": 0
}
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Arbitrarily altering the response body would be pretty weird. It's something else. Have you looked at the unparsed response body? Check they're sending the same request: same headers, URL, domain, and cookies.

Comment: What code generates that?

Comment: I'd assume that the response is containing the same variables multiple times and the two libraries are parsing them differently?

Look at the raw response and also show the code how you build the request with HTTParty. 

Also: why HTTParty? Just use raw net/http (which has a somewhat weird API but will reduce the number of gems which is always a good idea)

Comment: I've never heard of a Rubyist saying "Why HTTParty? Just use raw net/http." HTTParty exists for a reason: we all use it, and only suckers use net/http directly.

Comment: I checked raw response again: puts response.to_a, puts response.inspect, puts response.body. I coudn't find any difference. I think I'll give a try with Faraday and see if I get any difference..

Comment: You can use the [httplog](https://github.com/trusche/httplog) gem to take a look at the raw response as it comes over the wire, and compare it with the parsed response object HTTParty turns that into. Maybe that will give a clue. If you compare Postman with your own code, you can't be sure that the request is 100% identical, so the response might not be either.